JS class variable is always undefined even though it's assigned and is never assigned to undefined, inconsistently showed by DevTools as well
I am having a strange situation where a variable is assigned (and I made sure the assigned value is not undefined) but the value is always undefined. Strangely enough when inspecting the value by hovering it in DevTools, it shows the correct value but the evaluated expression in the console is still undefined and the code acts as if it's undefined:

Here is all the code that involves this.#lastDownload:
customElements.define("popup-page", class extends HTMLElement {
    // ...
    #lastDownload = 0;
    // ...

    async #download() {
        // ...
        this.#lastDownload = 0;
        // ...

            for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
                // ...
                const id = el.downloadId = await this.#attemptItemAsync(url, maxCon, addDelay);
            }
    }

async #attemptItemAsync(url, maxCon, addDelay) {
        try {
            if (addDelay > 0) {
                const now = Date.now();
                if (now - this.#lastDownload < addDelay) {
                    await sleepAsync(now - this.#lastDownload);
                }
                this.#lastDownload = now;
            }
            
            // ...
        }
        catch {
            return;
        }
    }
});

As you can see, there is no way #lastDownload gets assigned undefined. However after even running line 90 (now is a number and I checked and the value is a correct number), it is still undefined.
What am I missing?
UPDATE: apparently it's a Microsoft Edge bug, I tried sideloading the same extension in Google Chrome and the bug doesn't happen. Tried running again on Edge and the bug still happens.
UPDATE 2: yes it seems to be a MS Edge bug, reported here on GitHub

// Always call super first in constructor. Whats up with the hashes?

@danielRICADO thanks, not showed in the code but I already have that call (TypeScript would not let me compile without that call).

hmm  maybe specific to a browser. you might need a polyfill for the #privateDeclaration or customElements itself

@danielRICADO I am running on the latest Edge. Private #variable and customElements have been working fine for a long time so I think something else is happening here to Edge.

Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.
